# Остановить поток Thread Android

Tags: java, android, многопоточность, сокет

На сокетах в отдельном потоке написана отправка сообщения серверу, поток вызывается после нажатия кнопки "Отправить", так вот первое сообщение отправляется, когда пытаюсь второй раз вызвать этот же поток для отправки - приложение вылетает. Предполагаю что его нужно как-то удалять, дезактивировать.

```
public void sendmsg (View v) {
    send.start();
 }

Thread send = new Thread(new Runnable() {

    public void run() {

        try {
            Socket s = new Socket("IP", 8000);

            PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream());
            writer.write("Сообщение серверу");
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            s.close();

        }

        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
   });
```

Comment: Один поток можно запустить только один раз. Чтобы запустить задачу ещё раз - нужно создать новый экземпляр потока (`send = new Thread(...)`) и запустить уже его.

Comment: Старый экземпляр удалится при создании нового экземпляра?

Comment: Если поток завершился (дошёл до конца метода `run()`) и на него нет других ссылок, то да - экземпляр будет уничтожен при следующей сборке мусора.

Comment: А новый экземпляр нужно создавать в методе sendmsg, да?

Comment: Видимо да. В общем случае там, где нужен новый поток, перед вызовом `thread.start()`. P.S. вообще с сокетами работают несколько иначе - примерно так, как Вы начинали, открывать/закрывать его на каждый пакет данных как-то неправильно. Поищите какой-то внятный пример, лучше простенького, но рабочего приложения целиком, потому что в статейках типа "ткни сюда, напиши это - Ура! Ты - программист"))) опускают детали для краткости и не видно общей схемы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Один поток можно запустить один раз.

```
public void sendmsg (View v) {
  new Thread(new Runnable() {

public void run() {

    try {
        Socket s = new Socket("IP", 8000);

        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream());
        writer.write("Сообщение серверу");
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
        s.close();

    }

    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}).start;
}
```

но в таком случаем при закликивании каждый раз будет создаваться новый поток. Думайте как оптимизировать, это может быть экзекутор или создайте условия при котором поток будет работать до тех пор пока это необходимо.

как вариант

```
    Thread(Runnable {
        // тут инициализируете что Вам надо, например сокет соединение
        while (isEnabled) { - //булевая переменная которая отвечает за работу потока, объявите ее на уровне класса со значением true, а когда надо остановить присваивайте false. Поток выйдет из цикла и умрет.

            // тут как-то проверяйте есть новые смс для отправки. если есть отправляйте
            Thread.sleep(2000)// Усыпляйте поток на время (тут 2 секунды) 
        }
    }).start()
```

Comment: Спасибо. Но предыдущие потоки ведь после выполнения кода будут удаляться, правильно?

Comment: да, почитайте про потоки, после того как поток закончил работу он "убивается"

Comment: Спасибо. А зачем создавать условия при котором поток будет работать до тех пор пока это необходимо, если мне нужно только отправить сообщение на сервер, после чего его необходимость исчезает.

Comment: Создание потока не самая легкая операция для системы, тут надо смотреть как часто будут отправляться смс. Если это не постоянная операция - можно и так. Если вам надо раз в 2-3 секунды что-то отправлять, тогда надо подумать про оптимизацию.

Comment: Вот как раз часто. Но как в таком случае лучше оптимизировать? В какую сторону смотреть? Вы написали про условие. Но в моем случае условие заключается лишь полным выполнением кода внутри потока.

Comment: делаете бесконечный цикл и в нем проверяете, я сейчас обновлю ответ, скину пример на Котлине

Comment: Дело в том, что у меня поток как раз вызывается когда отправляется сообщение, поэтому не приходится внутри потока проверять отправляет ли пользователь сообщение. Пользователь нажимает кнопку отправить - поток открывается.

Comment: Я понял что Вы говорите. Спасибо!